# How can I skip a directory and its child directories when checkout out

Tags: git

I use the following to checkout source from Webkit

```
git clone git://git.webkit.org/WebKit.git WebKit
```

How can I skip a directory and its child directories when checkout out the code?
I want to do that to save disk-space.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, you can't.  Git manages the entire working tree as a cohesive entity.  This question does not "map" to the logic behind git.

Answer (score 1):

Disk space is so cheap it's almost free these days.

Since Git manages a "repository" as a single cohesive unit, there is no way to be selective about the subdirectories that are created when checking out a working copy. The best you can do is to convince the upstream publisher to manage a large, optional subdirectory as a Git [*submodule*](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/GitSubmoduleTutorial).